# Partial differential equation first order non-homogenous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Quick question, I cannot seem to figure to out where I am making a mistake.

The question is:
$$ u_x + sin(x) u_y = u $$
with boundary conditions:
$$u (0,y) = y^2$$

So my approach was to do:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = sinx, \frac{du}{dx} = u$$

Solving for the homogenous equation is:
$$y + cos(x) = y_0$$
$$ u(x,y) = f(y + cos(x))$$

Also I know that solving the du/dx equation:
$$ u(x,y(x)) = ke^x$$
$$ k = u(0,y_0) = (y_0)^2$$
Plugging in the $y_0$ value:
$$k = (y + cos(x))^2$$
Then the solution should be:
$$ (y+cos(x))^2 e^x$$

But the solution says it should be:
$$ (y + cos(x) -1)^2 e^x$$, not sure where I went wrong.

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is right. The reason is that, on a point $(0,y_0)$ on the initial curve, the combination $y+\cos x$ is equal to $y_0+1$ and then on the characteristic $u=u(y_0)=u(y+\cos x-1)$, etc.

Comment: I see, I completely forgot to evaluate the cos(x). Thank you for clearing it up.